# Catching (non-standard?) exception in MS VS 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

my code produces an External Exception E06D7363 and aborts. I can narrow the source of the problem down to the creation of an array of objects of a class (called CChunk). The syntax is as follows:

```
Array_of_Chunks = new CChunk[i];
```

whereas i is an integer which is created at runtime. Array_of_chunks is a member variable of another class (CDm), defined in its constructor as

```
CChunk *Array_of_Chunks; //private member variable of CDm
```

and the new statement is part of a member funcion of class CDm.
To find out what sort of problem is causing the abortion I have tried try- catch with

```
#include <exception>
```

but an exeption is only thrown if I use the

```
catch(...)
```

statement. A

```
catch (const std::exception& e)
```

statement is ignored. Thus, my understanding is that the exception is a non-standard exception.

Further on, the exeption is only thrown when I attempt to create larger arrays (i in the range of 800).

I need advice how to identify the true nature of the problem. Please be patient with me, I am not an experienced coder...

Comment: Your visual studio debugger has a [*ton* of exception options](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/02/23/the-new-exception-settings-window-in-visual-studio-2015/) for breaking on a plethora of exception conditions raised, including *structured* exceptions. You could always just enable catching darn near everything and let it catch it for you. It should take you directly to the throw-point. Hit the Debug/Exceptions menu option.

Comment: That exception code seems to be a Visual C++ specific compiler exception when handling [structured exceptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680657(v=vs.85).aspx) ([reference 1](https://support.microsoft.com/sv-se/help/185294/prb-exception-code-0xe06d7363-when-calling-win32-seh-apis), [reference 2](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?333591-Just-what-I-is-I-exception-E06D7363)). As such it is not based on the standard C++ exception hierarchy. Your best bet to solve seems to be to catch it in the *debugger* to find out more.

Comment: It is an entirely normal C++ exception, produced by a `throw`.  Seems you didn't put the try/catch in the right place.  Or it was produced by a library that was linked with a very old version of the CRT.  Use the debugger to see where it was thrown.  Debug > Windows > Exception Settings > tick the C++ Exceptions checkbox.  Look at the Stack Trace window when the debugger stops.  If it is a wonky library then you might not see any source code.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. The debugger stops when the program usually is aborted and comes up with a CMemoryException, triggered by TRNExe.exe, which is the calling program. Does that actually mean that TRNExe.exe causes the problem? Or would TNRExe.exe be mentioned anyway, even if the dll causes the problem?
Thank you!